# React build Application change data source?

Tags: reactjs, web

I used create-react-app to build an app.

This app had require some image, and this image was used in Home Page

If I just want to change that image in Home Page or some new text change, how could I do?

I don't think it's that simple just re-run build. (or it's just like that?)

I don't have any real world web experience.

I want to know how real server how to do that. I think real website could not be off line even in

second.

Comment: Imagine the web, as it's simplest form, is just a folder in your computer. You can have images, text files, documents etc. However, when you open up your computer to the web, your files, images, text, documents will all be web/internet accessible. A webpage is **just a interface to "your computer"** and "your computer" in this case acts as a server. When you change a image (e.g. image.jpg) from an apple to an orange, people who try to view the image will then see an orange instead of an apple.

Comment: ReactJS in this case, is just a language that tells the browser how to display text/images/videos, and how to behave when you interact with it. Since you want to learn react, you should really **first**, read the documentation @ https://create-react-app.dev *then* when you have a proper question, you can come to SO.